# Sync block required for Collections.synchronizedList.add()?

Tags: java, multithreading

My understanding of this is that a `synchronized` block keeps other threads from accessing until such time as that block terminates; that is, they are put on hold till then via a lock held by the currently executing class (?).

So I wrap a `for` block which iterates over a list and then calls `clear()` on that list directly thereafter, in a `synchronized` block. as I can't afford to have other threads adding to the list between those two sets of operations. This is in accordance with the docs, which say,

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   collection when iterating over it...

However I can't figure for sure whether I need to do the same when I am `add`ing to the list. I am guessing not, since in my case the order of `add` operations from different threads is not important. I guess that what I'm unsure of is whether un`synchronized` *modify* operations might have any negative impacts?

Comment: If adds can occur in any order, no additional locking is required.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey. Don't you want to put that in an answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need locking when you have multiple operations which must work together.  In the case of an Iterator, you will perform any operations over the life of the loop.

If adds can occur in any order, no additional locking is required.

> I wrap a for block which iterates over a list and then calls clear()

From your use case, it sounds like a BlockingQueue (is thread safe without synchronized) or even an ExecutorService (which combines a thread pool with a queue) would be a better choice.

Comment: And yes, I am using prioritised job pools via an `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Unless you are *very* careful, you can write a complex priority based thread pool which it's very useful or doesn't do what you think.  Often it's better/simpler to have a couple of thread pools for critical and non-critical tasks.

Comment: It's alright Peter, though thanks for the advice. My setup has been working for a few months, so I know it's stable. And it's a necessity for large-scale AI and procedural world generation. I am very impressed with what Java supplies out of the box in this regard, though it has its occasional niggles.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that you synchronize on Collection itself

```
Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);
     ...
synchronized (c) {
     for(Object o : c) {
      ....  
}
```

other threads calling any methods of `c` will be blocked until you leave the block. No other synchronization is necessary

Comment: @NickWiggill Any time you have multiple operations which must work together.

Comment: @Nick all synchronized collection methods "add" or any other are synchronized on collection itself. Thus after current thread entered synchronized (c) {} all other threads will block on c.add() or any other c method